# are <script> elements a security issue in views? is there other way to pass values from model to js?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, security

In my application i need to localize some javascript messages. So I use renderaction to get the appropriate strings from a resource file by reflection and serialization via json. See code at bottom

Code works fine and javascript json object is correctly updated when i change localization.

But then i read this article

https://blog.uploadcare.com/vulnerability-in-html-design-the-script-tag-33d24642359e

I also need to include google analytics script and other views need to include other `<script>` elements for js configuration vars. Every object in this elements is freezed and primitives are declared constants, the rest of js is in separate files.

Am I just paranoid or this is actually a serious security issue? Is there a way to load model data and values into javascript without `<script>` elements?

call in layout view

```cs
     @{Html.RenderAction("GetJsMessages", "Localization");}
```

code in controller (ClientMessages is the .resx class)

```cs
        [OutputCache(VaryByCustom = "culture", Duration = 7200)]
        public ActionResult GetJsMessages()
        {
            string clientJsLocalizationJson
                = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                 typeof(ClientMessages)
                        .GetProperties()
                        .Where(p => !p.Name.IsLikeAny("ResourceManager", "Culture")) // Skip the properties you don't need on the client side.
                        .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(null) as string););

            return PartialView("_jsLocalizationPartial", clientJsLocalizationJson);
        }
```

_jsLocalizationPartial view code

```cs
     @model string

     <script>
        var jsResources = Object.freeze(@Html.Raw(Model));
     </script>
```

Comment: That doesn't have any attacker-controlled content, so it isn't vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your codes I think you are fine. Provided that you are not rendering any user input on the page or if you are that is html encoded.

You can get the data on an Ajax call or load them in hidden field and read using javascript. But those are not necessary.

`<script>` element is ok to be used as long as you have other security measures in place. Google for how to secure javascript on a page.